# C++: Text was not handled properly, first \r\n was not parsed

Tags: c++, string, android-ndk

I'm porting a open source game client from PC to Android, however when dealing with NPC chat, some lines are not parsed correctly:

**Original text from server:**

```
formatted_text_ = "Now...ask me any questions you may have on traveling!!\r\n#L0##bHow do I move?#l\r\n#L1#How do I take down the monsters?#l\r\n#L2#How can I pick up an item?#l\r\n#L3#What happens when I die?#l\r\n#L4#When can I choose a job?#l\r\n#L5#Tell me more about this island!#l\r\n#L6#What should I do to become a Warrior?#l\r\n#L7#What should I do to become a Bowman?#l\r\n#L8#What should I do to become a Magician?#l\r\n#L9#What should I do to become a Thief?#l\r\n#L10#How do I raise the character stats? (S)#l\r\n#L11#How do I check the items that I just picked up?#l\r\n#L12#How do I put on an item?#l\r\n#L13#How do I check out the items that I'm wearing?#l\r\n#L14#What are skills? (K)#l\r\n#L15#How do I get to Victoria Island?#l\r\n#L16#What are mesos?#l#k"
```

Second line **"How do I move"** is not started as a new line, other lines ended with \r\n are parsed normally by following a new line.

**How \r and \n are handled:**

```
            switch (text[first]) {
                case '\\':
                    if (first + 1 < last) {
                        switch (text[first + 1]) {
                            case 'n':
                                linebreak = true;
                                break;
                            case 'r':
                                linebreak = ax_ > 0;
                                break;
                        }

                        skip++;
                    }

                    skip++;
                    break;
```

When line break is true or length exceeds max width, a new line should be added:

```
        bool newword = skip > 0;
        bool newline = linebreak || ax_ + wordwidth > max_width_;

        if (newword || newline) {
            add_word(prev, first, last_font, last_color);
        }

        if (newline) {
            add_line();

            endy_ = ay_;
            ax_ = 0;
            ay_ += font_.linespace();

            if (!lines_.empty()) {
                ay_ -= line_adj_;
            }
        }
```

[image]
**How formatted_text_ was handled:**

https://github.com/speedyHKjournalist/OpenMapleClient/blob/521af535bb65fb231296d02f1d19a6f38e77673d/app/src/main/cpp/src/IO/UITypes/UINpcTalk.cpp#L141

https://github.com/speedyHKjournalist/OpenMapleClient/blob/73ddd15f443cc0ab9f796ce362a67d73e5e453ad/app/src/main/cpp/src/Graphics/GraphicsGL.cpp#L617

https://github.com/speedyHKjournalist/OpenMapleClient/blob/73ddd15f443cc0ab9f796ce362a67d73e5e453ad/app/src/main/cpp/src/Graphics/GraphicsGL.cpp#L657

Comment: Based on your code, you are suggesting the server is sending a literal sequence of **backslash**, `r`, **backslash**, and `n` to indicate an end of line?  Is that correct?  Because that is whack.  Or do you have a misunderstanding of how backslash escape sequences work within string literals.

Comment: Is the server sending literal backslashes. Or are you possibly confused by how backslash escape sequences work?  Maybe the debugger is confusing you by showing `\r\n` in the watch window to indicate carriage return and line feed.  Is that possible?

Comment: I debugged with Android Studio, the server is indeed sending \r\n

Comment: If you are hovering over a variable name in the debugger and you see a `\r\n`, you do realize that's two characters, and not four. Right?

Comment: If you see `\\r\\n` in the debugger, then server is literally sending 4 bytes.  But `\r\n` is two bytes. The backslash is the escape to indicate "special char".  Which is it?

Comment: I can see \r\n in the debugger, should be two bytes.

Comment: Exactly.  So trying to parse a literal `\\` followed by an `n` is not the right way.  I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks, so the problem should be here: https://github.com/speedyHKjournalist/OpenMapleClient/blob/73ddd15f443cc0ab9f796ce362a67d73e5e453ad/app/src/main/cpp/src/Graphics/GraphicsGL.cpp#L729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `\r\n` sequences are two bytes. `\r` is carriage return. and `\n` is a line feed char.  Windows prefers `\r\n` for end of line.  Unix and everywhere else (including Android) prefers just `\n` for end of line.

Easiest thing to do is simply treat `\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n` as valid end of line markers. So let's just normalize your formatted string such that \n is the defacto end of line marker:

```
    std::string s = formatted_text_;
    std::string t;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == '\r') {
            t += '\n';
            if ((i + 1 < s.size()) && (s[i + 1] == '\n')) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            t += s[i];
        }
    }
```

The outcome of that is that `t` is now a string of the form:

```
"Now...ask me any questions you may have on traveling!!\n#L0##bHow do I move?#l\n#L1#How do I take down the monsters?#l\n#L2#How can I pick up an item?#l\n#L3#What happens when I die?#l\n#L4#When can I choose a job?#l\n..."
```

Since we now have one delimiter to indicate end of line, we can use `getline` to parse into a list of lines.

```
    std::istringstream iss(t);
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(iss, line, '\n')) {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
```

`lines` is an array (vector) of strings as follows:

```
#L0##bHow do I move?#l
#L1#How do I take down the monsters?#l
#L2#How can I pick up an item?#l
#L3#What happens when I die?#l
#L4#When can I choose a job?#l
#L5#Tell me more about this island!#l
#L6#What should I do to become a Warrior?#l
#L7#What should I do to become a Bowman?#l
#L8#What should I do to become a Magician?#l
#L9#What should I do to become a Thief?#l
#L10#How do I raise the character stats? (S)#l
#L11#How do I check the items that I just picked up?#l
#L12#How do I put on an item?#l
#L13#How do I check out the items that I'm wearing?#l
#L14#What are skills? (K)#l
#L15#How do I get to Victoria Island?#l
#L16#What are mesos?#l#k
```

e.g. `line[2]` is equal to `#L2#How can I pick up an item?#l`.  Those format specifiers of `#L2` and `#l` for your game - I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

note: `#include <string> #include <vector> and #include <sstream>` for the above code to work.